# Language translator using java

Tags: java, translation, language-translation

I want to create a language translator using java. All translators are using the resources from google translate so they are not standalone. but i want to create a standalone application which doesnt use internet to translate the text. please guide me how to do this

Comment: Your question is a little broad for just one answer

Comment: have a look at http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/phrasal/

Comment: Go to scholar.google.com and search things like 'computer language translation' and read all the resulting papers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to translate just 1 word you need a database or file which have the translations. Just read in a word, search for it and put out the other value. If you want to translate complete texts - have fun, that's a whole other world.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a simple argument.
You need to study the theory of machine translation.
Start reading some info about that on wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_translation